Download universal package without az cli using REST API
I want to download universal  package without az cli, how to get the download link? I don't want to use az cli. Is it possible?
URL:
https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<org>/<project>/_apis/packaging/feeds/<feed>/UPack/packages/<package-name>/versions/<version>?api-version=7.1-preview.1

Response:
{
    "id": "<package-name>",
    "name": "<package-name>",
    "version": "<version>"
}


I am afraid that there is no such Rest API can download the Universal Package in Azure DevOps for the time being.
The REST API you shared in question only supports getting the version information of the Universal Packages. And other existing REST APIs cannot download the package.
Currently, Azure DevOps only supports using Azure DevOps CLI(without pipeline): az artifacts universal download or Download Universal Package task(In Pipeline) to download the Universal Packages
I can fully understand your requirement. Here is a suggestion ticket with the same requirement: Download Universal Package REST API.
